# How to check if 2 statements are true

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I'm trying to make my discord bot send a message that the server admin wants but i dont know how to check if the user using the command is an admin and has mentioned a channel,
im trying to use `if (message.member.hasPermission('ADMINISTRATOR'))`
in this code

```
            message.channel.send(developerEmbed);
        }
        else {
            let targetChannel = message.mentions.channels.first();
    
            const args = message.content.split(" ").slice(2);
            let userMessage = args.join(" ");
            targetChannel.send(userMessage);
            message.delete();
            
        }
```

the only problem is that i don't know how to implement both of the statements at the same time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```js
if(message.member.hasPermission('ADMINISTRATOR') && message.mentions.channels.first())
```

See && operator: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_AND

Comment: if i try that i get the error ```TypeError: Cannot read property 'send' of undefined```

Comment: can you specify the line please

Comment: I want to check if the user is an admin and if he didn't specify a channel with this ```if (message.mentions.channels.size === 0){
            message.channel.send(developerEmbed);```
but the problem is when i try your solution i get the error about ```message.channel.send(message)``` that send is not an function

Comment: It looks like you have a problem that's not related to my solution, could you please upload the whole code?

Comment: note that ```if(message.mentions.channels.first())``` will check if the first-mentioned channel is undefined so it will be the same as ```if(message.mentions.channels.size === 3)```

Comment: Sorry for the late response, here is my whole code
(the code was too long for a comment so its a pastebin link)
https://pastebin.pl/view/d00d3fcd